# How convert Json string to key value pair in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, json, parsing

```
   {
      "transactionId" : XXXXX,
      "uri" : "https://XXX.XXXXXXXX.XXXX/XXX/XXX",
      "terminalId" : 1,
      "action" : "CHARGE",
      "amountBase" : "3.00",
      "amountTotal" : "3.00",
      "status" : "CAPTURE",
      "created" : "2015-01-24T07:24:10Z",
      "lastModified" : "2015-01-24T07:24:10Z",
      "response" : 
       {
           "approved" : true,
           "code" : "00",
           "message" : "Approved",
           "processor" : 
            {
               "authorized" : true,
               "approvalCode" : "XXXX",
               "avs" : 
                     {
                         "status" : "NOT_REQUESTED"
                     },
            }
  },
  "settlement" : 
   {
        "settled" : false
   },
  "vault" : 
   {
        "type" : "CARD",
        "accountType" : "VISA",
        "lastFour" : "1111"
  }

}
```

Comment: This JSON does not fit into "key-value-pair" i.e. a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this has got a lot of down votes but no one is actually offering any advice. The json above is not a natural fit for a Dictionary but should be de-serialized into an object.

Response, settlement and vault all have their own properties and as such should be their own objects.

Look into Json.net for a good way to convert json into your c# objects. If you are stuck on how you would represent this object in C# then you need to read a good book on programming specifically one that covers Object Orientated programming.

Stack is a great resource for these questions but you need to try and show you have done your own research first otherwise others will just mark your questions down.

Answer (score 1):

Are you receiving a POST that contains a JSON ?

You can use something like this , create an instance of Request class and assign the JSON obj to that instance. You should be able to access the parameters via request instance.

The basic structure will look some thing like this :

```
public class Request
{
    public Int64 transactionId { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public int terminalId { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string amountBase { get; set; }
    public int amountTotal { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastModified { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
    public Settlement settlement { get; set; }
    public Vault vault { get; set; }
}
public class Response
{
    public bool approved { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Processor processor { get; set; }
}
public class Processor
{
    public bool authorized { get; set; }
    public string approvedCode { get; set; }
    public AVS avs { get; set; }
}
public class AVS
{
    public string status { get; set; }
}
public class Settlement
{
    public bool settled { get; set; }
}
public class Vault
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string accountType { get; set; }
    public string lastFour { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: FYI You can auto-generate the above by dumping the json into http://json2csharp.com/.